# Softether VPN Setup: Automatic Script executed from git

Tags: bash, git, shell, scripting, raspberry-pi3

Am kind of new to bash scripting but i was wondering if it is possible to create automatic installations script for softether vpn server on raspberry pi to be executed from git and if it is possible how do you create one as I cant find any of the tutorial online to implement what i want, I tried to create mine and I failed miserably. any help will be appreciated.Thanks

```
sudo su
cd /root/

wget https://www.softether-download.com/files/softether/v4.34-9745-rtm-2020.04.05-tree/Linux/SoftEther_VPN_Server/32bit_-_ARM_EABI/softether-vpnserver-v4.34-9745-rtm-2020.04.05-linux-arm_eabi-32bit.tar.gz
tar xzf softether-vpnserver-v4.34-9745-rtm-2020.04.05-linux-arm_eabi-32bit.tar.gz && rm softether-vpnserver-v4.34-9745-rtm-2020.04.05-linux-arm_eabi-32bit.tar.gz

cd vpnserver && sudo make
cd ..
sudo mv vpnserver /usr/local && cd /usr/local/vpnserver/
sudo chmod 600 *
sudo chmod 700 vpnserver vpncmd

sudo ./vpnserver start
sudo ./vpncmd
ServerPasswordSet

echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 | ${SUDO} tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo net.ipv6.ip_forward = 1 | ${SUDO} tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf

sudo cat >> /etc/init.d/vpnserver << EOF
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:                     vpnserver
# Required-Start:               $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:                $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:                2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:                 0 1 6
# Short-Description:            SoftEther VPN 1.0 RC2
# Description:                  Start vpnserver daemon SoftEther VPN 1.0 Server
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON=/usr/local/vpnserver/vpnserver
LOCK=/var/lock/vpnserver

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
start)
sleep 3
log_daemon_msg "Starting SoftEther VPN 1.0 Server" "vpnserver"
$DAEMON start >/dev/null 2>&1
touch $LOCK
log_end_msg 0
sleep 3

;;

stop)
log_daemon_msg "Stopping SoftEther VPN 1.0 Server" "vpnserver"
$DAEMON stop >/dev/null 2>&1
rm $LOCK
log_end_msg 0
sleep 2

;;

restart)
$DAEMON stop
sleep 2

$DAEMON start
sleep 5

;;

status)
    if [ -e $LOCK ]
    then
        echo "vpnserver is running."
    else
        echo "vpnserver is not running."
    fi
;;
*)

echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
EOF

sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vpnserver
sudo update-rc.d vpnserver defaults

systemctl enable vpnserver
sudo /etc/init.d/vpnserver start
sudo /etc/init.d/vpnserver stop
sudo /etc/init.d/vpnserver restart

wget -qO- https://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

Comment: At which point is it failing ? Besides this, in the source repository of softether on github there are systemd service scripts available. use them instead of the old initd.

Comment: the script up there doesn't execute at all when made as bash script unless i have to execute one line at a time in a shell command @Marco

Comment: remove the first two lines, or better remove all the `sudo` and run the script with `sudo`. This will most probably do what you want. BUT better use systemd from the source repository.